# Best way to get huge data

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

First let me describe my case:

I need to store around 200extra detail of each user. I am using wordpress. Now there is a default function to save data associated with user. But i am not sure what should i use. In my case i will need some of data in 1 page. For example i need 20 data in one page and 100 data in another. User may need 20 data at once or 100 data at once.

I didn't designed my database table yet. After understand the best way of query i will design it. To get 200 data (fields) of a user if it is ok to make 200 search query then i will user wordpress default meta table. Structure is given below.

```
----------------------------------------------
| umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
----------------------------------------------
```

From structure above you can see wordpress save each data of a single user as a single row. SO in this case for one user's 200 data wordpress will save 200 row. And to retrieve the data i have to make 200 queries.

Now if it is better to get all data of user by a single query and save it in session then i will create my own table. Structure is given below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
| User_ID | User_detail_1 | User_detail_2 | User_detail_3 | ...
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the above structure i can save all those 200 data in one row and can get all in one query and then save to session and user when needed somewhere.

Now in my site i dont need all data in one page. On one page i might need 100 data and in another page i might need 50 data. So considering my case should i save each data as a row(using wordpress meta table) and then make 100 queries for the page where i need 100 data and make 50 queries where i need 50 data?

Or i should use one query and get all the data, save in SESSION then use data from SESSION where 50 or 100 data is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need 200 queries to fetch 200 values!

For example, if in 1 page, you need to fetch 3 fields having the keys "my_data_1", "my_data_2", and "my_data_3", you can fetch them all in a single sql query using "OR" in the where condition.

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value from TABLE_NAME where meta_key='my_data_1' OR 
meta_key='my_data_2' OR meta_key='my_data_3';
```

This will return all ur values in a single result table in a single query:

```
------------------------
 meta_key | meta_value |
------------------------
my_data_1 | my_value_1
------------------------
my_data_2 | my_value_2
------------------------
my_data_3 | my_value_3
------------------------
```

Then you can process them in your application